# iPod interaction

Tags: mfc

say I want to write a windows application in which i want to transfer some files to my connected iPod device or any other MP3 player.

how can i accomplish that ?

Comment: what about iPhone interaction ? is there a library similar to libipod.sourceforge.net ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at this library.
http://libipod.sourceforge.net/